# Where does ViEmu save mappings and stuff?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, viemu

Where does ViEmu save my custom mappings and settings I use ? Something like _vimrc, but I can't seem to find it.

*This is the same [question](https://superuser.com/questions/22818/where-does-viemu-save-my-mappings-and-stuff) I've asked a little while ago at SU; but then thought it might be more fitting here.*

Comment: In gVim, you can infer it from typing :ed $VIM\ and hitting tab -- it expands the $VIM keyword for you. Does that work in ViEmu?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would recommend asking on [the ViEmu forum](http://www.viemu.com/forum): the author is fairly active there.

Answer (score 4):

The file is called "_viemurc" can be saved in either `%HOME%` (`%HOMEPATH%` on modern versions of Windows) or the program files directory for ViEmu.

http://www.viemu.com/forums/viewtopic.php?id=37